# Trivial change in SQL query causes increased network receive throughout and commit count after

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, spring-jdbc, postgresql-11

- Postgres 11.12 on Amazon RDS
- 4 billion rows in table
- 1000 new rows a second, inserted in batches of 100

Some time ago I added a new column

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD COLUMN my_new_column BOOLEAN NULL;
```

This column was completely not used, nothing was explicitly inserted there. However when I changed the `INSERT` query to explicitly set the value of this column to `null`, then:

- inserting new rows in batches by the client executes 5x slower
- network receive throughout grows around 5 times
- commit count grows around 3 times

Any idea what can be causing that? Example below

Before:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
ON CONFLICT (column1, column2)
    DO UPDATE
    SET column3 = excluded.column3
```

After:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2, column3, my_new_column)
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', null)
ON CONFLICT (column1, column2)
    DO UPDATE
    SET column3 = excluded.column3
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: What is a "commit count"?  How are you measuring it?

Comment: This seems like an issue with your client driver, which you don't describe.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tip from @jjanes I managed to fix the issue. The bottleneck was somewhere around driver (Spring - JDBC). It looks like the type for that 'null' value could not be resolved causing this whole overhead. Once I explicitly defined the type, then the issue got fixed. Example below:

Before:

```
    val queryParams = mapOf("myNewColumn" to null)
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, queryParams)
```

After:

```
    val queryParams = MapSqlParameterSource().apply {
        addValue("myNewColumn", null, Types.BOOLEAN)
    }
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, queryParams)
```